# jQuery Mobile caching link to relative page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm having an issue with jQuery Mobile links to a dynamic page.

I have a list of links generated with a relative link like this:

```
<a href="#page2?q=Foo">Foo</a>
<a href="#page2?q=Bar">Bar</a>
```

And on the page `page2`, I use the data in the query string to populate fields dynamically.

The problem is, if I click on `Foo`, go back, and click on `Bar`, JQM actually takes me to `#page2?q=Foo` again. I tried setting `data-cache="never"` on `page2` but with no luck. Any idea why the link isn't actually going to what it is, but the first that was clicked since page load?

Edit: example site <s>here</s> [fixed]. Just click on any item, go back, and try to go to another one. You'll get the first again.

**Edit:** I've tried setting data-dom-cache="false" which doesn't help, as it isn't that the page is cached, but that the link is cached (maybe?). I've also tried removing the page from the DOM, but then when I try to re-navigate to the page, I am unable, as it is gone.

I tried to work around this problem by simply programmatically setting the page value on click/tap, but this doesn't work when trying to load a specific page (for bookmarking/deep-linking).

**Edit 2:** I think I have found a related issue that may be causing this one. When I load up each page, I parse out the document.location.search. Oddly, with URLS like

```
http://.../#route-page?route=test
http://.../#route-page?route=test2
```

document.location.search should return `?route=test` and `?route=test2` and document.locations.hash should return `#route-page` for both. What I'm actually getting is empty strings for document.location.search and the entire thing for document.location.hash: `#route-page?route=test`.  Am I using these two properties wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sure if you fixed this already, as the links in your example take to different pages every time?

Anyway, this piece from [jQuery Mobile's documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html) might be related to your problem:

> jQuery Mobile does not support query parameter passing to internal/embedded pages but there are two plugins that you can add to your project to support this feature. There is a lightweight [page params plugin](https://github.com/jblas/jquery-mobile-plugins/tree/master/page-params) and a more fully featured [jQuery Mobile router plugin](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router) for use with backbone.js or spine.js.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I did fix it yesterday, and this bit of info is what helped me. Instead of using one of the plugins, I set `rel="external` to prevent ajax loading of the pages, and thus, removal of the query parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You have a multi-page document and you link the first page with the second one using the page id (example: href="**#route-page**?route=50%20Grit").

The Javascript function getParameterByName uses the window.location.search in order to get the URL. But the URL still remains the same after the first page transition.

Try to use the following script instead of the getParameterByName:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) 
            {
                if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) 
                {
                    var urlObj = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(data.toPage);
                    var rex = /^#route-page/;
                    if ( urlObj.hash.search(rex) !== -1 ) 
                    {
                        var specificRouteName = urlObj.hash.replace( /.*route=/, "" );
        // The specificRouteName gives you the "route" parameter.               
                    }
                }
            });
    </script>
```

Below you can find an example which is based on your code. I hope this helps you.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.17/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h2 class="full-text">Climbing Areas</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="home-content" data-role="content">
            <ul id="locations" class="data" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" 
                data-filter-placeholder="Search for location, type, or route/problem name" data-filter-theme="a" >
                <li>
                    <a href="#route-page?route=mountain" data-transition="slide">Test1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#route-page?route=sea" data-transition="flip">Test2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of Home Page -->

    <!-- Route Page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="route-page" data-dom-cache="false" data-theme="a" data-cache="never">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) 
            {
                if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) 
                {
                    var urlObj = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(data.toPage);
                    var rex = /^#route-page/;
                    if ( urlObj.hash.search(rex) !== -1 ) 
                    {
                        var spesificRouteName = urlObj.hash.replace( /.*route=/, "" );
                        document.getElementById('tst').value = spesificRouteName;
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h2 id="route-header" class="full-text"></h2>
            <a href="#home" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="home">Home</a>

            <a href="#home" class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="arrow-l" rel="external">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div id="route-content" data-role="content">
            <h3 id="route-name"></h3>
            <p id="route-description"></p>
            <input id="tst" type="text" value="">
            <div id="route-colors" class="ui-grid-e">
            </div>
            <div id="route-images" class="ui-grid-a">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: You say, "But the URL still remains the same after the first page transition." That's the problem. It seems like a JQM bug. Your code didn't fix anything. pagebeforechange doesn't get fired. Even if it did, the code looks like it's doing the same thing, and would have the same problem as a result of the URL reverting to some cached version.

Comment: If you put the html I posted in a file and open it with a browser, you will see that route parameter is correctly retrieved in each page transition. The text input in the second page is dynamically filled with the value of the route parameter. Moreover the pagebeforechange is fired.

Comment: I've got this almost working. The one concern I have is that even though the page being shown is the correct, the URL always stays as the first one that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You're using document.location.search and document.location.hash wrong. A URL is structured so that the fragment (hash) comes after the query string (search). When you create a URL that has a ? after a #, the URL parser seeS that whole thing as the hash.

Ex:

`example.com?a=b#c` would have a `search` of `?a=b` and a `hash` of `#c`

vs.

`example.com#c?a=b` would have a `search` of empty string and a `hash` of `#c?a=b`

Comment: This is helpful, but interestingly, when I form my links the other (correct) way, jquery mobile removes the search portion. I.e., a link to "?a=b#c" results in only "#c".